# Powershell - return free and total space on disc

Tags: powershell

how to split this script to return free space on C: in one variable and total size in second please?

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk | Select-Object -Property DeviceID,@{'Name' = 'FreeSpace (GB)'; Expression= { [int]($_.FreeSpace / 1GB) }}, @{'Name' = 'Size (GB)'; Expression= { [int]($_.Size / 1GB) }}
```

[result of script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3o5t.png)

This script returning all in one table and i just need to split it to single variables.

Thank you.

Michal

Comment: `$result = Get-CimInstance ...; $variable1,$variable2 = $result.'FreeSpace (GB)',$result.'Size (GB)'` - assuming you only have one disk. But why? Wouldn't it be smarter to keep the values associated with the volume ID?

Comment: nice! Thank you. Main goal is check space on system disc and send it over api. And my system recieve it and draw graph by the time.